# method to prove that the transformation is bijective

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'd like to know the way to prove the transformation is bijective. For example,

(1) the transformation $x=\frac{\sin u}{\cos v}$ and $y=\frac{\sin v}{\cos u}$ is bigective from $\{(u,v): u>0, v> 0, u+v < \frac{\pi}{2}\}$ to $\{(x,y): 0< x,y <1\}.$

(2) the transformation $x=\frac{\cos v}{\cos u}$ and $y=\frac{\sin u}{\sin v}$ is bigective from $\{(u,v): 0< u < v < \frac{\pi}{2}\}$ to $\{(x,y): 0< x,y < 1\}.$

Note that both has Jacobian determinant $J(u,v)=1-x^2y^2.$

Please let me know if you have any comment for this question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just prove your Jacobian determinant is nonzero for all values of $x,y$. This is due to the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Inverse function theorem implies the invertible of the function  locally, doesn’t it?

Comment: Yes. If a function is invertible then it is a bijection.

Comment: In general, locally invertible function is not invertible in its domain.

Comment: In general, yes, but I'm fairly sure for a domain where every point is locally invertible the entire domain is invertible as all points within the domain are invertible.

Comment: I haven’t seen the result you wrote. There are a lot of counterexample for it. For example, $f(x,y)=(e^x\cosy,e^x\siny)$. Its Jacobian determinant is $e^{2x},$ but it is periodic w.r.t. $y.$

Comment: Yes but here the domain is not all real numbers or even enough for the functions to be periodic.